# Regex help needed not working for me

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I have a source string

```
<img src="./CaptchaServlet?rd=htb54m" class="flt"  id="captcha" height="33" width="110"/>
```

I want to extract the data between `CaptchaServlet?rd=xxxxxx"`.

I tried but not working pls help me anyone, my regex is as follows

```
r = New Regex("CaptchaServlet?rd=*(.+?)""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Compiled)
```

Comment: `CaptchaServlet?rd=([^""]*)`

Comment: this is not working :(

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

## Description

The expression `CaptchaServlet?rd=*(.+?)""` as you've written has a couple errors:

- The first `?` means to make the preceding `t` optional. I think you really meant to make the question mark a literal question mark, so you'll need to escape that as `\?`
- the `*` after the equals sign means too allow the `=` to appear zero or more time up to infinity times. It's is kinda ambiguous, and given your source string will likely have 1 or 0 equal signs then you might want to replace that `=*` with a `=?` which simply makes the `=` optional,

Personally I'd rewrite the expression to actively avoid some common problems with using regex with pattern matching in HTML. My expression would be:

- Capture the src attribute value
- works with double quoted, single quoted, and non-quoted values
- avoids tricky edge cases which normally trip up simple expressions

`<img(?=\s|>)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\ssrc=(['"]?)(.*?)\1(?:\s|>))(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*>`

[image]

Or if you're looking to extract just the `rd` query string value you could use: `<img(?=\s|>)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\ssrc=(['"]?)\.\/CaptchaServlet\?rd=(.*?)\1(?:\s|>))(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*>`. This will put the xxxxxx into capture group 2

## Example

[Live Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/rpFMXppww2)

**Sample Text**

Note the first two image tags have some very difficult edge cases

```
<img onmouseover=' img = 10; src="NotYourImage.png" ; if (3 <img && src="NotYourImage.png" && 6>3) { funRotate(src) ; } ; ' src="ImageYouAreLookingFor.png">
<img onmouseover=' src="NotTheDroidsYouAreLookingFor.png" ; if (x > 3) { funRotate(src); } ' src="http://another.example/picture.png">
<img src="./CaptchaServlet?rd=htb54m" class="flt" id="captcha" height="33" width="110"/>
```

**VB.Net Exmaple**

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim sourcestring as String = "replace with your source string"
    Dim re As Regex = New Regex("<img(?=\s|>)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|=""[^""]*""|=[^'""][^\s>]*)*?\ssrc=(['""]?)\.\/CaptchaServlet\?rd=(.*?)\1(?:\s|>))(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|=""[^""]*""|=[^'""][^\s>]*)*>
",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase OR RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace OR RegexOptions.Multiline OR RegexOptions.Singleline)
    Dim mc as MatchCollection = re.Matches(sourcestring)
    Dim mIdx as Integer = 0
    For each m as Match in mc
      For groupIdx As Integer = 0 To m.Groups.Count - 1
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames(groupIdx), m.Groups(groupIdx).Value)
      Next
      mIdx=mIdx+1
    Next
  End Sub
End Module
```

**Matches**

Group 0 gets the entire image tag
Group 1 gets the quote used to surround the src attribute, and is used to ensure the correct closing quote is matched
Group 2 gets the src value, or if you use the alternate regex above, will receive just the rd query string

```
[0][0] = <img onmouseover=' img = 10; src="NotYourImage.png" ; if (3 <img && src="NotYourImage.png" && 6>3) { funRotate(src) ; } ; ' src="ImageYouAreLookingFor.png">
[0][1] = "
[0][2] = ImageYouAreLookingFor.png

[1][0] = <img onmouseover=' src="NotTheDroidsYouAreLookingFor.png" ; if (x > 3) { funRotate(src); } ' src="http://another.example/picture.png">
[1][1] = "
[1][2] = http://another.example/picture.png

[2][0] = <img src="./CaptchaServlet?rd=htb54m" class="flt" id="captcha" height="33" width="110"/>
[2][1] = "
[2][2] = ./CaptchaServlet?rd=htb54m
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CaptchaServlet\?rd=[^"]*
```

...As long as double quotes never appear as part of your data, this will work. :)

And I highly recommend that you check out http://regexhero.net/, it will really help you when testing out .net regular expressions.

**EDIT:** Improved the regex. Before it only worked for alphanumeric characters.

Comment: @Arun sankar Is it because of the quote? You just need to escape that.